# How to define a table list with Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm looking for the definition of table lists in Angular Material. Currently I've found the `md-list` directive, but it doesn't allow me to display the table on the whole screen (e.g. like in Bootstrap with the col-md-12 etc.)

Is there a possibility to implement it?

Example code:

```
<div layout="row" class="layout-align-center-center">
    <md-list ng-cloak layout="column">
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="item in todos">
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
            </div>
            <md-divider></md-divider>
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show an image or better yet show a demo of how you want ti to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you are looking for.  But, you could try [md-data-table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table).

There are others as well.  This one seems to follow the Angular Material patterns pretty well.